# Deterministic Finite Automata of a simple arithmetic string

Tags: automata, dfa, deterministic

Would this DFA solve the problem to create a DFA that accepts simple arithmetic string.

e.g.

```
7        -> accepted
4+1      -> accepted
5-7      -> accepted
8*3      -> accepted
2/1      -> accepted

*        -> not accepted
/3       -> not accepted
5+       -> not accepted
```

I am thinking if I would want to accept negative numbers but this is not required, so I created this DFA

[image: DFA]

Comment: What do you mean by "simple arithmetic string"? Is 4 + 3 + 2 a "simple arithmetic string"? Do you allow parenthesis? Please give a precise definition.

Comment: stat your "simple arithmetic string"?

Comment: wah, forgot the start...thank yo for pointing out..